# Adding a viewcontroller to xcode causes exceptions in monodevelop

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller, monodevelop, popover

I just started out on Monodevelop 3.1.1. I opened the .xib file. I did a hello world program. Works fine. Now i created new monodevelop project and in that i am trying to use the popover style of iPad (i.e. if one clicks a button and we have a popover style for drop down).I added a viewcontroller to Xcode and I got this error.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
 at System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2) [0x000c6] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.9/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:126 
at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeMonitor.ScanForAddedFiles (IProgressMonitor monitor, MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeSyncBackContext ctx, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1 knownFiles, System.String directory, System.String relativePath) [0x00067] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.1-series/5d928ec4/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeMonitor.cs:214 
 at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeMonitor.GetChanges (IProgressMonitor monitor, MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectInfoService infoService, MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject project) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.1-series/5d928ec4/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeMonitor.cs:256 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeProjectTracker.SyncXcodeChanges (IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00017] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.1-series/5d928ec4/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeProjectTracker.cs:497
```

So where do we add a viewcontroller if we need to add one in MonoDevelop/Xcode?And how do we do it?More questions coming. If you need more info please ask.Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in MonoDevelop. You should be able to add view controllers in Xcode and it should get imported back into MonoDevelop.

I'll look into fixing this bug if it still exists in Xamarin Studio (aka MonoDevelop 4.0).

Update: This should be fixed in 4.0.1